# How is ownership of mutex (lock) implemented?

Tags: c, multithreading, locking, mutex

I am a little bit confused trying to implement a very simple mutex (lock) in C. I understand that a mutex is similar to a binary semaphore, except that the mutex also enforces the constraint that the thread that releases the lock, must be the same thread that most recently acquired it. I am confused on how the ownership is kept track of?

This is what I have so far. Keep in mind that it is not completed yet, and is suppose to be really simple (uniprocessor, no recursion on mutex, disabling interrupts as mutual exclusion method, etc).

```
struct mutex {
    char *mutexName;
    volatile int inUse;
};
```

I believe I should add in another member variable, i.e., whoIsOwner, but I am kind of confused as what to store there. I assume it has to be something that can uniquely identify the thread trying to call the lock? Is this correct?

I have a thread structure in place that has a "char *threadName" member variable (along with others), but I'm not sure how I would access this from within the mutex implementation.

Any pointers/hints/ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: "volatile" != thread-safe.  If the OS scheduler is able to preempt execution to switch to another thread (as almost every modern OS scheduler can) then this will not be thread-safe.  (Please tell me you are using compare-and-swap?)  Note that if your mutex is not designed to be re-entrant, then you don't actually need any ownership concept; you have only "owned" and "not owned" states -- ownership isn't important if the thread owning the mutex cannot recursively own it.

Comment: If you were using pthreads, I'd say whoIsOwner would be the pthread_t value returned by pthread_self() (which you would call as part of the lock() command).  Of course, if you were using pthreads, you probably wouldn't need to be implementing your own mutex functionality either... :/

Comment: There isn't any reason to actually record who holds the lock if it isn't a recursive lock.

Comment: I am not using pthreads, rather a scaled down OS simulator with its own thread implementation. Can we forget the fact that it is no recursive, just for now? I, for example, would like to implement something along the line of a function "do_i_hold_lock(struct mutex *)"

Comment: Many (most?) mutex implementations do not check that the mutex is released by the thread that most recently grabbed it. It is up to the programmer to enforce the correctness of the mutex locking/unlocking.

Comment: @Jesus: You should not need to ask "do I hold a mutex."  If your code depends on this then your code is wrong.

Comment: @cdhowie My code doesn't depend on it, I am just wondering how it could be checked.

Comment: Well, about the only way you could check this would be to store the owning thread identifier, whatever data type that might be.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could implement the mutex as an atomic integer which is `0` when unlocked, and which takes the value of the locking thread's ID to indicate it's locked. Of course access to the variable has to be atomic, and suitably fenced to prevent reordering (acquire-release fence pairs suffice).

Ultimately you can of course never prevent *yourself* from shooting yourself in the foot; if you really want you can overwrite the mutex's memory by force from another thread, or something like that. You'll only get the correct behaviour if you use the tools correctly. With that in mind, you might be satisfied with a simple bool for the locking variable.

Answer (score 2):

```
uint32_t  semOwner;
```

If the above field is 0, then it is available.  If it is "owned", then let it be set to the ID of the owning task, or thread, or Process ID/Thread ID combo (or some other combination that may suit your system).

Hope this helps.

Comment: How do I make reference to the member variables of the thread within my lock functions?

Comment: Scratch my last comment, I was confused about something. I just made a global variable that always points to the current thread that is running.

Comment: As a side note, `uint32_t` is probably the wrong type to use here... on 64-bit systems I would expect thread identifiers to be 64-bit.  For example, thread identifiers on win32 are `HANDLE` which (through several typedefs) is equivalent to `void *`.